# Query where does not exists all records of subquery

Tags: sql

I have two tables structures and inserts as follows

**Products:**

```
productno   Products    State
    1001      a         liquid
    1002      b         liquid
    1003      c         liquid
    1004      d         Solid
    1005      e         Solid
    1006      f         Solid
```

**Orders:**

```
orderno Productno
101 1001
101 1003
101 1002
102 1001
102 1004
102 1005
102 1006
103 1006
104 1002
105 1004
106 1001
106 1002
106 1003
106 1006
```

And insert statements

```
CREATE TABLE product (productno NUMBER,product VARCHAR2(10),states VARCHAR2(15));
INSERT INTO product (productno,product,states) VALUES (1001,'a','liquid');
INSERT INTO product (productno,product,states) VALUES (1002,'b','liquid');
INSERT INTO product (productno,product,states) VALUES (1003,'c','liquid');
INSERT INTO product (productno,product,states) VALUES (1004,'d','Solid');
INSERT INTO product (productno,product,states) VALUES (1005,'e','Solid');
INSERT INTO product (productno,product,states) VALUES (1006,'f','Solid');

CREATE TABLE orders (ordersno NUMBER,productno NUMBER);
INSERT INTO orders (ordersno,productno) VALUES (101,1001);
INSERT INTO orders (ordersno,productno) VALUES (101,1003);
INSERT INTO orders (ordersno,productno) VALUES (101,1002);
INSERT INTO orders (ordersno,productno) VALUES (102,1001);
INSERT INTO orders (ordersno,productno) VALUES (102,1004);
INSERT INTO orders (ordersno,productno) VALUES (102,1005);
INSERT INTO orders (ordersno,productno) VALUES (102,1006);
INSERT INTO orders (ordersno,productno) VALUES (103,1006);
INSERT INTO orders (ordersno,productno) VALUES (104,1002);
INSERT INTO orders (ordersno,productno) VALUES (105,1004);
INSERT INTO orders (ordersno,productno) VALUES (106,1001);
INSERT INTO orders (ordersno,productno) VALUES (106,1002);
INSERT INTO orders (ordersno,productno) VALUES (106,1003);
INSERT INTO orders (ordersno,productno) VALUES (106,1006);
```

I want to build a query to list down orders which does not have all Liquid products.

For Example

1) orderno 101 & 106 should not be in output as all 3 liquid products(1001,1002,1003) are there.

2) orderno 102 Should be in output as only one liquid products (1001) is there. Same with orderno 104

3) orderno 103 & 105 Should be in output as non of liquid products in there.

Comment: 1) What flavor of sql are you using? 2) What have you tried so far?

Comment: please add expected result and explain along with it ,also tag the DBMS you are using like SQLServer/Oracle/Mysql....

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use aggregation.  The following returns the orders that are have a liquid or solid product, but not all of them:

```
select o.ordersno, p.state
from products p join
     orders o
     on p.productno = o.productno
group by o.ordersno, p.state
having count(distinct o.productno) < (select count(p2.productno)
                                      from products p2
                                      where p2.state = p.state
                                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT o.ordersno
FROM orders o JOIN product p ON o.productno = p.productno
GROUP BY o.ordersno
HAVING string_agg(distinct p.states, '') <> 'liquid';
```

If you use another DB, search for varchar's AGGREGATE FUNCTION. All databases have an aggregate function for varchar.

Answer (score 0):

Select all  products what status is not *liquid* and join this with orders by product identificator. To exclude duplicated rows use `DISTINCT` modifier.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    orderno
FROM
    Orders 
JOIN
    (SELECT *
    FROM
        Products
    WHERE
        NOT State = 'liquid'
    ) ON Orders.Productno = Products.productno;
```